# I need the postgres Interval value - `"week": {"hours": 12, "minutes": 6, "seconds": 41, "milliseconds": 793 }` to be `12:06:41.793`

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using the node-postgres and in the response for rows I'm getting as
`"week": { "hours": 12, "minutes": 6, "seconds": 41, "milliseconds": 793 }`

But I'm expecting the result as `12:06:41.793` similar while reterving the data from pg-Admin-local.
can anyone suggest/answer this issue.

Comment: I guess pgAdmin just displays this formatted representation of `{ "hours": 12, "minutes": 6, "seconds": 41, "milliseconds": 793 }` so you can do the same

Comment: No pg admin displays `12:06:41.793` like this. Not as an object. I just need the value.

Comment: Yes, it uses `{ "hours": 12, "minutes": 6, "seconds": 41, "milliseconds": 793 }` (or just internal epresentation in milliseconds) ans shows it as a string. YOu also can do this. Is there any difficulties to do so?

Comment: But I need value same as like this `12:06:41.793`

Comment: In this case you need to add a custom attribute in `attributes` prop uisng `Sequelize.fn` and a SQL function to convert an interval to a string representation